# How to properly include header files with msvc in vscode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, msvc12, vcpkg

I did `vcpkg install mman.h && vcpkg integrate install`.

Now default C\CPP Linter in VSCode sees that header file, but compiler doesnt.

My tasks.json file :

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/I\\C:\\Users\\ansga\\vcpkg\\packages\\mman_x86-windows\\include\\mman\\sys mmmapTest.c",
                "/Fe:",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}",

            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
```

Still gives me error on `#include <mman.h>`.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: `mmapTest.c
c:\Users\ansga\OneDrive\Pulpit\notGithub\C_tests\mmapTest\mmapTest.c(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mman.h': No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1`

Comment: If I am correct, `/I` is to specify an include _path_. You let it end in a `.c` _file_. That is not a path.

Comment: There is a space `..\\sys\\ {SomeProjectFileToLink.c}`, but even if I end it like `\\sys\\` The same error still occurs, I cant figure out whats wrong here.

Comment: You have a backslash between the `/I` and the start of the path: Windows paths that include a drive letter do not start with a single backslash.

Comment: Without it its the same error unfortunately. I took that syntax from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2019 Cause local dir starts with backslash there, like in git-bash or cygwin. But I dont know what Im doing, c\cpp with its prehistoric useless imports is such a mess.

Comment: Ok, I guess it should look like this `/IC:\\Users\\ansga\\vcpkg\\packages\\mman_x86-windows\\include\\mman\\sys\\` and the VSCode should be started from VS dev console, at least it works. Cheers.